# How can I have Django user registration single step (instead of two step)process with email compulsory?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

I want Django to send an email to user email-address with Login details once admin adds a new user to admin site.So I tried using Django signals for that but just becoz django user registration is a two step process signals get notified in first step only and called email function without email address(which comes in second step).
My signal code:

```
def email_new_user(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs["created"]:  # only for new users
        new_user = kwargs["instance"]
       send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)


post_save.connect(email_new_user, sender=User)
```

So what i tried to overcome this problem.I use this code in admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_joined', 'last_login')
    search_fields = ['username', 'email']
    filter_horizontal = ('user_permissions',)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

This makes all registration process a single step process and my signals start working and sending mail to user_id on new user addition.But the problem came after this were:

**1. User password is not converted into hash and is visible while entering into form,that makes user not able to login into admin site.**

**2.Email field in form is not compulsory which I want to be compulsory.**

Please help me  :(

**[EDIT]**

```
I tried your code But I m still at same place where i was before posting this question.
the code i used in my admin.py is:
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.naturefarms.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import *

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email',)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm

admin.site.unregister(User)

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )




admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

[image: This is the output I m getting using this code which is even not converting password field into hash.]

Answer (score 9):

If you look in django.contrib.auth admin.py, you'll see that the UserAdmin class specifies the add_form as UserCreationForm.

UserCreationForm only includes the 'username' field from the User model.

Since you're providing your own UserAdmin, you can just override the add_form to a custom UserCreationForm that includes the fields you need to make your signal work properly.

Hope that helps you out.

[Edit]

Here's the UserCreationForm from contrib.auth forms.py:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and password.
    """
    username = forms.RegexField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
        help_text = _("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages = {'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"), widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text = _("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with that username already exists."))

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1", "")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Notice the fields = ("username",) tuple which excludes all other fields on the User model. You need something like:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email',)
```

then you can use that as the add_form in your custom UserAdmin:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
```

It's pretty late in my part of the world, but I'll see if I can get a working sample for you tomorrow.

[Edit]

Ok, here's the necessary changes you'll need to make to make this work. I've tested it using Django 1.3:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

admin.site.unregister(User)

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

I didn't see that the UserAdmin had an add_fieldset property initially. That's why the email field wasn't displaying in the add form.

Comment: Could you Please show me a small example for this.....i m trying but its not working out

Comment: I tried your solution but nothing has changed on the admin form,everything is same............but I would like to thank you for helping.

Comment: I added some additional code that adds the email field to the form. It's working for me on Django 1.3.

Comment: Hey Brandon i tried even your new code but still the problem is same as i described initially posting question, i have updated my question please look at it and tell what I am doing wrong.Thanks

Comment: @anks I believe your problem is that you are trying to subclass UserCreationForm. Instead, create a new form. MyUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):...

Answer (score 1):

From [this example](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2011/12/19/quick-example-of-extending-usercreationform-in-django) try defining email in your custom UserCreationForm as required=True:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email',)
```