# Modifying Django UserCreationForm

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I wanted to add more fields to the standard Django UserCreationForm so I went ahead and subclassed it inside of my app's forms.py file and ended up with this:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
    first_name = forms.CharField(label = "First name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(label = "Last name")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "username",)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I then went ahead and created a custom ModelAdmin for my Users, which looks like this:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    inlines = [ProfileInline,]


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Class, ClassAdmin)
```

No matter what I do, however, the new CustomUserCreationForm does not show up when I go into the Admin page and try to add a new user. Where am I screwing up?

EDIT: It seems that the form is not being displayed, but is being used. If I try to add a new user using just the username and password fields that the typical UserCreationForm has, I get an error, which promptly goes away when I remove the add_form line in my ModelAdmin. Why is it not displaying?

I also do not have any admin templates in my local app directory. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to add the fields you've added to the add_fieldsets property of your custom user admin class.

```
#example:
add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
```

A user had a similar question the other day: [How can I have Django user registration single step (instead of two step)process with email compulsory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628452/how-can-i-have-django-user-registration-single-step-instead-of-two-stepprocess/6630174#6630174) which involved creating a custom user admin form as well.

Comment: How does one change the "Enter a username and password" text that appear above this (first) form?